# Spring data jpa JOIN does't work in @Query

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa. I wrote a native query but it doesn't work. Here is my entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="view_version")
public class ViewVersionDom {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="view_id")
private ViewDom view;

private Integer version;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="datasource_param_id")
private DatasourceParamDom datasourceParam;

private String description;

@Column(name="created_date")
private Date createdDate;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="view_permission")
public class ViewPermissionDom extends BaseDom {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="view_id")
private ViewDom view;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private UserDom user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="group_id")
private GroupDom group;

private Boolean read;

private Boolean write;

private Boolean execute;
```

Here is the query:

```
@Query(value = " SELECT v FROM ViewVersionDom v LEFT JOIN ViewPermissionDom vp ON v.view.id = vp.id " 
         + " where (v.view.user.id = ?1 OR (vp.read=true and (vp.user.id=?1 or vp.user.id is NULL and vp.group.id is NULL or vp.group.id in (?2)))) "
         + " ORDER BY v.view.name", nativeQuery=true)
public List<ViewVersionDom> findUserViews(Long userId, List<Long> groupIds);
```

At first when I didn't write nativeQuery=true the application didn't build and I got an exception 'path expected for join jpa'. When I set the settings nativeQuery=true the application is started, but when I call the function I got the following error:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - [ERROR: relation "viewversiondom" does not exist Position: 16] 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]
```

Does there any other settings or annotation that will resolve the problem? 
I have searched in google, but in all cases 2 tables connected with each other directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not a SQL query (assuming, you don't have a column `v` in one for your tables).

Also the Table `viewversiondom` doesn't exist or is not accessible to the database user used for the connection.

Also when mapping native queries to domain objects you should have a look at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-980